# Divide by Zero Error on a Bookstore template

Tags: exception, pricing

I'm trying to work with a template on a bookstore site (M2.3.6). I added a new configurable product with 2 configurations and when I did, I got this error:

Error filtering template: Warning: Division by zero in /home2/crippenl/public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/Sm/amabook/Sm_RecentlyViewed/templates/slider-v2.phtml on line 101

The code is:

getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                                        getPrice();
                                            $finalPrice   = $_product->getFinalPrice();                     
                                            $save_percent  = 100 - round(($finalPrice / $defaultPrice) * 100);
                                           
                                            if ($finalPrice

Any thoughts on this? I've been working on this for hours with no luck. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the variable  `$defaultPrice` has some value ?  As well as you could either use `$block->getProductPrice($_product)` or  `$block->getPrice()` in your template file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* returns your product price without tax and before all the rules in your store currency without formatting */
$defaultPrice = $_product->getPrice(); 
  
$finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice(); // returns your product final price 

$save_percent = 100 - round(($finalPrice / $defaultPrice) * 100);
```

BTW with PHP 7 you can also handle these exceptions

```
try {
  $save_percent = 100 - round(($finalPrice / $defaultPrice) * 100);
} catch (\DivisionByZeroError $exception) {
} catch (ErrorException $error) {
}
```